# Using javascript to write anchor links dpending on environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page where a user can click a link and register on the site.  Example:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/register.html">
```

As we develop the page we test in development, staging, and production environments.  Is there a way to have the register link point to development, when in development, so that we don't have to edit the page and change the link every time we test in each environment?

Ex for dev:

```
<a href="https://d-www.example.com/register.html">
```

Ex for stage:

```
<a href="https://s-www.example.com/register.html">
```

Maybe better asked: is it possible for javascript to handle the URL structure to switch between dev, staged production?

Comment: Have you considered relative links?

Comment: You can also look at using the base html5 tag and change that instead of your anchor tags, if(for whatever reason) you switch between your links taking you from one environment to another.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: If you use different hosts for your dev and stage, you can use location.hostname in JavaScript to differentiate these from each other

Answer (score 0):

There are three solutions:

First using javascript if condition and hide/show what you need based on URL, that because you will need Server Side Rendering to update your html after loading page because content and html tags already loaded, but in case you don't have you can manage it by CSS, and this not good enough.

```
//here i check if url contain dev word or stage word
if(window.location.href.indexOf("dev") > -1) {
   document.getElementById("stageAnchor").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("devAnchor").style.display = "block";
} else if (window.location.href.indexOf("stage") > -1) {
   document.getElementById("devAnchor").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("stageAnchor").style.display = "block";
}
```

or Using JQuery append

```
//here i check if url contain dev word or stage word
if(window.location.href.indexOf("dev") > -1) {
   $("#anchorDIV").append("<a href='#'>some dev Description</a>");
} else if (window.location.href.indexOf("stage") > -1) {
   $("#anchorDIV").append("<a href='#'>some stage Description</a>");
}
```

Another solution is trying  you can [check how it works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) and it will be based on URL too and I recommend to use this